# Web API for Git

Tags: python, ruby, perl, git, asp.net-web-api

I am looking for web API (not HTML web interface) for Git written in Perl, Python, Ruby, or may be Erlang. I need read-only access to the repository for logs and commits info. Does anybody know about it?

What does web API mean? Web API is web service as described in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service). I want to send a request via SOAP, XML-RPC, JSON-RPC, or any other protocol, and receive back data only.

Comment: Huh? Why not just use the git protocol?

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you are looking for from a "web API"? If you want to use a programming language to interact with git repos over a network, there are bindings for pretty much every major "scripting" language, as Brandon points out below. If you want something that's not obvious from those, we're going to need more details to be able to help out.

Comment: SLaks, git protocol is not suitable for me. E.g., if I want to see log of remote repository, then I must have to clone it.

Comment: jeremiahd, I updated my question.

Comment: People are not asking for clarification because they don't know the definition of "Web API".  They are asking because they don't understand what *you want to do*.  Linking to a Wikipedia definition insults everyone's intelligence.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you are referring to by "web API", but there are bindings for many languages for libgit2 at http://libgit2.github.com/. Also, if you're trying to access information on GitHub repositories, check out http://developer.github.com/.

Comment: @Denis: you need to invest much more time on programming